# How to delete multiple records in grid using kendoui

Tags: kendo-ui

I am having a grid with checkboxes for each item in the grid. I need to delete the multiple checked items in the grid. How can i do that in kendo ui.

Regards,

Sri

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When the button is clicked use jQuery to find all TR elements which contain the checked checkboxes and then use the [removeRow](http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/grid#removerow) method. Something like:

```
$.each($('#GridName :checkbox:checked').closest('tr'),function(){
    $('#GridName').data().kendoGrid.removeRow($(this));
})
```

Comment: why is grid databound called for each row? i process each grid row on databound and after removing them, databound is called for each row and the row still thinks the removed row is there so i just get a lot of js errors.